# Copper saute pan metal lining is melting?

Tags: copper-cookware

So, I tried using a copper (I bought 2nd hand recently) pan to brown some beef. The lining is melting and bubbling.

Am I not supposed to use it for this?

Or has it been lined with something other than tin?

Thanks,

I am worried to eat from it now.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the type of pan you experienced this with (so I don't have something similar happen).  Is it a solid copper pan with a tin exterior lining?  Do you have a link to a description and an image of the pan, or a similar one?

Comment: Hi, it's a copper pan with a tin **interior**. They look like this: (https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/JWwAAOSwD0NdUcy5/s-l1600.jpg) I had them over a high heat for searing - a lesson learned!

Comment: Thank you for the description and image.  I'm not sure I've ever seen a pan with that type of construction.  Interesting!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You overheated it, tin melts at 450 F . It may have a few per-cent of other metals in the tin that would raise the melt temperature slightly.It should be fine now except if the surface is now rough ,it will be difficult to clean. The tin can be remelted and smoothed. Unfortunately that requires some skill/experience. I have retinned at least one, I added some pure tin (not commonly available- no solder is pure tin.). I managed to get an OK result, not as good as the original very smooth surface.

Comment: Thanks! The tin did not get too rough, so it should remain usable for now. I should have realized as I did this to another pot of mine, it went dry when I wasn't looking. I think I can get pure tin on ebay. I don't think I have a hot enough heat source to do re-tinning.

I will use cast-iron for searing from now on.

Comment: A stove top ( gas or electric ) easily get hot enough to melt tin .The tin" wants' to wet the copper, it will tend to smooth itself, but not a mirror finish.

Comment: To the point made by @am4ci about not having a heat source to do re-tinning, You don't need too much heat to work with tin. While I haven't tried re-tin my own copper yet, I have melted bars of tin in a cast iron pot for casting projects using nothing more than a $10 hibachi and BBQ charcoal.

Comment: This is really interesting, I will certainly try it at some point. @blacksmith From what I have read there are a few additional ingredients required, such as a flux and something to strip the original lining, did you use these? or did you get workable results without? I've seen videos: one using tin pellets melted in the pan and another using a small bar wiped around the inside.

Comment: The tin and copper do not oxidize (much) at the low temperature so I did not use flux